# How to perform this python post request

Tags: python, api, python-requests, request

I am new to python requests and do not know how to call this API with a post request.
This is the information I got:

```
POST /whatcaristhat?key=<CarsXE_API_Key> HTTP/1.1              
Host: http://api.carsxe.com             
Content-Type: text/plain             
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/2019_Acura_RDX_A-Spec_front_red_4.2.18.jpg
```

What I got so far is:

```
import requests

api_key = 12345
url = f'http://api.carsxe.com/whatcaristhat?key={api_key}'
data = b'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/2019_Acura_RDX_A-Spec_front_red_4.2.18.jpg'

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url,
        data=data,  
        headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

But I get this error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You probably aren't supposed to have the `<` and `>` literally in the URL.

Comment: Or, better, skip the `json.dumps` step and change `data=data` to `json=data`.

Comment: I left out < and > but now I get error 500. Am I supposed to put /whatcaristhat?key=<CarsXE_API_Key> in the url even? And what to you mean with json=data?

Answer (score 2):

This API takes either an image URL or a base64 encoded image. As of now, `data` is defined as a set. The fix is pretty straightforward:

```
data = b'https://upload.wikimedia.org/whatevertheurlis.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I don't get any answer (not even a status code) from the API. What could I do?

Comment: @Bernardo Can you give more details? No response code is only possible if the requests is timing out, that means the problem is on the API side. I don't have an API key to check it myself.

Comment: @Bernardo please delete the comment with the API key. I'll follow up shortly

Comment: Alright. Thank you!

Comment: @Bernardo The problem is on the API side (I get status 500). There isn't much that can be done besides talking to their support

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your effort anyway!